# postfix unable to receive external emails

Tags: email, postfix

I have setup an email server with postfix and dovecot. Installation went fine but I am not able to receive emails from external users(gmail, yahoo etc) but I can send email to external users. 
When an external user send an email , it gets bounced backed with the following error:-

Technical details of permanent failure:

```
    Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain mail.intelliswift.com by mail.intelliswift.com. [14.141.53.97].

    The error that the other server returned was:
    554 5.7.1 <farhan@mail.intelliswift.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied
```

I can see some error logs in the maillog file as following:-

```
    Jul 11 15:27:18 mail postfix/smtpd[4056]: connect from mail-ob0-f169.google.com[209.85.214.169]
    Jul 11 15:27:20 mail postfix/smtpd[4056]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ob0-f169.google.com[209.85.214.169]: 554 5.7.1 <rupesh@mail.intelliswift.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied; from=<farhan.ziya@gmail.com> to=<rupesh@mail.intelliswift.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ob0-f169.google.com>
    Jul 11 15:27:21 mail postfix/smtpd[4056]: disconnect from mail-ob0-f169.google.com[209.85.214.169]
```

Please note that, I have setup the MX record properly. My domain is mail.intelliswift.com and its pointing to an IP 14.141.53.97 and it has a MX record as mail.intelliswift.com.
Please find below the output of postconf :-

```
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    command_directory = /usr/sbin
    config_directory = /etc/postfix
    daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
    data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
    debug_peer_level = 2
    home_mailbox = mail/
    html_directory = no
    inet_interfaces = all
    inet_protocols = all
    mail_owner = postfix
    mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
    manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
    milter_default_action = accept
    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
    mydomain = intelliswift.com
    myhostname = mail.intelliswift.com
    mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
    myorigin = $mydomain
    newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
    non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
    proxy_interfaces = 14.141.53.97
    queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
    readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
    sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
    sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
    setgid_group = postdrop
    smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
    smtp_use_tls = yes
    smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unknown_client,permit
    smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,permit
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
    smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
    smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
    smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
    smtpd_use_tls = yes
    tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
    unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Does the user `farhan@mail.intelliswift.com` exist on your server?

Comment: yes, the user "farhan" exist as a linux user. Please note that user "farhan" is able to send emails to internal and external users and also receiving emails from internal users. its only not receiving emails from external domains.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't setup virtual domains or users. Unless you want that explicitly, you probably forgot it.

Comment: i want to send and receive emails using linux users not virtual users. Please let me know if i have to create a virtual user in order for me to receive emails from external domains. I m very new to postfix hence i might ask very basic questions. please understand.

Comment: When using Linux users, you don't need virtual users. I've never actually setup Postfix to work like that, so I can't see right off the bat what is wrong.